# Couldn't load the data for this visual

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, msbi

I created th following DAX expression so that I can have the age group of the customers and deployed it in the SQL Server Analysis services [image: Age Group]

Next, I wanted to use it in power bi.
But, the problem is that i got th following error.
[image: Power Bi Error]

Comment: My french is not that good, something about pregnance. Please translate so we might see if we can help you.

Comment: Thank you @Aldert for your reply.
Here is the translate of the error "The query referenced calculated column '<ColumnName>' which does not hold any data because evaluation of one of the rows caused an error."

Comment: With the importing of the report, is the DateOfBirth column still a date? Is it possible your DateOfBirth has empty cells?

Comment: HI @Aldert, yes the DateOfBirth column still have the Date Format and I don't have any empty cells